# Yodlee - How to get information about all accounts without transactions?

Tags: yodlee

Using jsonsdk/DataService/getItemSummaries (which no longer appears in the documentation oddly), I can get a list of all items, accounts, and their balances and error statuses.  However, it also returns all transactions for accounts, regardless of dexLevel you set (which seems to do nothing on this call).

The REST API talks about /account/summary/all​ http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/Account%2F%2FSummary%2F%2FAll but

a) It's completely different than every other call, and returns a completely different data structure.
b) This call returns nothing if you have only one account and it's still in a connecting status (as opposed to the one above, which will show accounts which are still being added/refreshed).

Long story short, what call can we use to return all items and their accounts, but not the transactions?

Answer (score 0):

The getItemSummaries API returns all the data including transactions and hence the data returned is huge and hence we don't want our clients to use this API, so it's been removed from the document. We are working to get a variant to this API which returns all data except transactions depending on the extent levels.

So in the mean time you will need to call [getItemSummariesWithoutItemData](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesWithoutItemData) and once you get the itemIds then you need to call [getItemSummaryForItem1](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1) with correct data extent to get details of each Item and then consolidate it.

Comment: What you are suggesting has almost twice as bad performance as the already poor performing /getItemSummaries.  In my testing it took an average of 2 seconds to return data for 3 Items (with 1-2 accounts each) with /getItemSummaries, where it took almost 4 seconds on average to call getItemSummariesWithoutItemData, and then do subsequent calls to getItemSummaryForItem1 (all with lowest extent levels).